# A topology exercise about compactness and Hausdorff

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $0^{\prime}$ denote a point that is not an element of $(-1, 1)$, and let $X = (-1,1)\cup\lbrace 0^{\prime} \rbrace$. Let $X$ be equipped with the topology generated by $(-1,a), (a,1), (-1,b)\setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace \cup \lbrace 0^{\prime} \rbrace, (c,1) \setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace \cup \lbrace 0^{\prime} \rbrace$, where $-1<a<1, 0<b<1, -1<c<0$. (We can think of $X$ as $(-1,1)$ with $0$ split in two. (Folland 4.37)

(a) Show that $X$ is not Hausdorff

(b) Show that $[-1/2,1/2]$, $[-1/2,1/2]\setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace \cup \lbrace 0^{\prime} \rbrace$ are compact but not closed in $X$ and their intersection is not compact.

I think for (a) $0$ and $0^{\prime}$ cannot but separated by open sets but I have no idea how to formally prove it. For (b) I'm trying to use the finite open subcover definition to show the compactness but that approach didn't quite work. The non-closedness also seems intuitively true but I'm not sure how to formally prove it.

Does anyone have solutions or ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspicion that $0$ and $0'$ can’t be separated by disjoint open sets is correct. Here’s a straightforward approach. Suppose that $U$ is an open nbhd of $0$ and $V$ an open nbhd of $0'$. Show that there are $a\in(-1,0)$ and $b\in(0,1)$ such that $(a,0)\cup\{0\}\cup(0,b)\subseteq U$ and $(a,0)\cup\{0'\}\cup(0,b)\subseteq V$. Conclude that $U\cap V\ne\varnothing$.

To show that such $a$ and $b$ exist, you could show that every intersection of finitely many members of the subbase given in the statement of the problem is equal to an intersection of just two members of it. Every such intersection that contains $0$ or $0'$ has one of the two forms that I gave above, so those sets are bases at $0$ and $0'$. In fact you’ll find that these two-fold intersections give you a base of open intervals, the only complication being that if $a<0<b$, then there are two $(a,b)$ intervals, one containing $0$ but not $0'$, the other containing $0'$ but not $0$. Thus, $X\setminus\{0'\}$ has exactly its usual topology, and $X\setminus\{0\}$ is identical apart from the name given to the point in the middle.

Now let $K=\left[-\frac12,0\right)\cup\{0\}\cup\left(0,\frac12\right]$ and $K'=\left[-\frac12,0\right)\cup\{0'\}\cup\left(0,\frac12\right]$; you’re to show that $K$ and $K'$ are compact but not closed in $X$. Once you’ve done the work for (a), showing that $K$ and $K'$ aren’t closed is easy: $0'$ is a limit point of $K$, and $0$ is a limit point of $K'$. The argument for compactness is the same for both sets. Given an open cover $\mathscr{U}$ of $K$, say, there must be some $U_0\in\mathscr{U}$ that contains $0$. The topology on $K\setminus U$ is identical to the topology on $\left[-\frac12,\frac12\right]\setminus U$ in $\Bbb R$, so $K\setminus U$ is compact, and only finitely many members of $\mathscr{U}$ are required to cover it.

That’s really the whole argument; what I’ve left for you are the details needed for the results in the second paragraph; that’s really the heart of both parts.

Comment: Thank you Brian. For your (a)'s argument to work, would I need to show these two sets are bases at $0$ and $0^{\prime}$? I'm not quite sure how to prove something is a base at one point.

Comment: I didn't quite get your approach for (b). Can you elaborate a bit? Thank you.

Comment: @jane: You’re given a subbase for the topology, so you know that the collection of intersections of finitely many members of that subbase is a base for the topology. You can show that every intersection of finitely many members of the given subbase is actually equal to an intersection of two members, so the collection of two-fold intersections is a base for the topology. The sets that I described are the two-fold intersections that contain $0$ or $0'$, so they give you bases at $0$ and $0'$. It might help to show explicitly that the subspace topology on $X\setminus\{0'\}$ is just the usual ...

Comment: ... topology on $(-1,1)$ and is homeomorphic to the subspace topology on $X\setminus\{0\}$: the two subspaces are identical apart from the name attached to the point in the middle. I’m going to revise my comments on (b).